# Yii 2 vendor trouble

Tags: yii2

```
\composer.json

    {
        "name": "yiisoft/yii2-app-basic",
        "description": "Yii 2 Basic Project Template",
        "keywords": [
            "yii2",
            "framework",
            "basic",
            "project template"
        ],
        "homepage": "http://www.yiiframework.com/",
        "type": "project",
        "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
        "support": {
            "issues": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues?state=open",
            "forum": "http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/",
            "wiki": "http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/",
            "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/yii",
            "source": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2"
        },
        "minimum-stability": "minimum-stability",
        "require": {
            "php": ">=5.4.0",
            "yiisoft/yii2": ">=2.0.5",
            "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "*",
            "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "*",
            "amnah/yii2-user": "^5.0",
            "voskobovich/yii2-many-many-behavior": "^3.0",
            "2amigos/yii2-date-picker-widget": "~1.0",
            "intervention/image": "^2.3",
            "codeception/codeception": "*",
            "codeception/specify": "*",
            "wbraganca/yii2-videojs-widget": "~1.0"
        },
        "require-dev": {
            "yiisoft/yii2-codeception": "^2.0",
            "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "*",
            "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "*",
            "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "*"
        },
        "config": {
            "process-timeout": 1800
        },
        "scripts": {
            "post-create-project-cmd": [
                "yii\\composer\\Installer::postCreateProject"
            ]
        },
        "extra": {
            "yii\\composer\\Installer::postCreateProject": {
                "setPermission": [
                    {
                        "runtime": "0777",
                        "web/assets": "0777",
                        "web/uploads": "0777",
                        "yii": "0755"
                    }
                ],
                "generateCookieValidationKey": [
                    "config/web.php"
                ]
            },
            "asset-installer-paths": {
                "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
                "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
            }
        }
    }
```

trouble

```
> composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.7 requires bower-asset/punycode 1.3.* -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.6 requires bower-asset/jquery.inputmask 3.1.* -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.5 requires bower-asset/jquery.inputmask 3.1.* -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 dev-master requires bower-asset/punycode 1.3.* -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.x-dev requires bower-asset/punycode 1.3.* -> no matching package found.
    - Installation request for yiisoft/yii2 >=2.0.5 -> satisfiable by yiisoft/yii2[2.0.5, 2.0.6, 2.0.7, 2.0.x-dev, dev-master].

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
```

Comment: did you install the composer asset plugin? as in: composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.1.1"

Comment: yes   ///////////////////////////////////////////////////

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that one of the potential causes listed is that the package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum stability setting. This setting can have one of the following options (in increasing stability order):

- dev
- alpha
- beta
- RC
- stable

Each package stability is checked against the minimum-stability setting and when its less stable, it will be ignored when updating your project.

Change `minimum-stability` to `stable` for instance or poke around with some other options and rerun `composer update`.

Check [composer shema docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability) for more detailed information.

Comment: could you add more detail to your answer? maybe what that option actually means? this post was marked as low quality so please expand on your answer!

Comment: fair enough, i have elaborated